# Check if selected value is last in the array

Tags: php

I have function like this:

```
function ypg_delete_img($id, $img)
        {
            $q = $this->ypg_get_one($id);

            $imgs = explode(',', $q->image);

            if(count($imgs) > 1) :
                $z = ",";
            else :
                $z = "";
                $data['image'] = 'avatar_mali_oglas.png';
                $this->db->where('id_yellow_pages', $id);
                $this->db->update('yellow_pages', $data);
            endif;
            if($imgs[0] != 'avatar_mali_oglas.png') :
                $query  = "UPDATE `yellow_pages` ";
                $query .= "SET `image` = REPLACE(`image`,'". $img . $z ."', '')
                           WHERE `id_yellow_pages` = $id "; 
                $this->global_functions->delete_img('zute_strane', $img);
            $this->db->query($query);
            endif; 
        }
```

I need to check if **$img** is the last value in the array of **$imgs**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

```
if ($img == end($imgs)) {
   // $img is the last element of the array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check end() : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.end.php

Like : if($img == end($imgs))

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code.

```
if($imgs[count($imgs) -1] == $img)
{
   // $img is the last image
}
```

Hope this will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
  $lastitem = array_pop($imgs);
  if ($img == $lastitem) {
    // is last image
  }
?>
```

[array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) returns the last element of an array, after that you just need to compare the two values.